# LayerVault folder restore

Tags: asset-management

We've started using [LayerVault](https://layervault.com/) to manage PSD revisions and things were going well. However, we had a sync inconsistency and the web UI was showing two folders of the same name, one of them empty. After deleting the empty one, both folders were removed.

Deleting a folder in LayerVault's web UI deletes the local folder instantly and permanently.

Is there any way to restore a folder that has been deleted via LayerVault's web UI?

Comment: I'd suggest you ask LayerVault technical support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kelly here from LayerVault. For things like this, sending [support](https://layervault.com/support) an email is always the best way to go.

The address is support@layervault.com and one of us will get back to you as soon as we can.